# How to use a service as a type in Thrift

Tags: c#, thrift

When I compile this `example.thrift` file with command `thrift-0.11.0.exe --gen charp .\example.thrift` I got this error: **`Type "Interface1" not defined`**

```
service Interface1 
{
    void add(1:list<string> a)
}

service Interface2
{
    bool isThere(1:Interface1 item)
}
```

How to use `Interface1` as a type of a method in `Interface2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing interface references is not supported in Apache Thrift. You could pass a struct with a service end point (hostname/ip, port and service name) however, then the receiver could use those coordinates to make a call back if that is what you are after.